# awk last argument before NF?

Tags: awk

I tried to print the argument before `$NF`. However `$NF--` doesn't do the trick. What is the solution to this? Problem is, I dono how many args I get, so I always need `$NF` and the arg before.

Kind Regards

Juergen

```
host -t ptr 1.1.1.1 | awk '/pointer/ {num=split($0,a, "."); print a[num-2] "." a[num-1] ;}'

foo.tld
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `$(NF - 1)` to get the next to last field. So in your case:

```
awk '{print $(NF - 1), $NF}'
```

Comment: aha, so I was close :o, Thanks!1